# What device can I use to duplicate a MIFARE ISO 14443A (13.54 MHz) card?

Tags: rfid

I'm not familiar with how these devices work. I'm looking to duplicate an ID card for ease of use and this is all the information I can find on it:

MIFARE ISO 14443A (13.54 MHz)

So, is there a simple cloner or duplicator that supports this? If not, is there an arduino device or something else that can do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't these cards designed to not be duplicated? That said, it depends on whether they actually designed the system to not allow duplicate cards.

Comment: @immibis they are. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mifare is a protocol that does cryptographic exchange with a secret that you cannot read. Basically, a secret question and answer game, with an uncloneable secret inside the chip. It can't be copied.

Unless it's cryptographically unsound.

Mifare classic is cryptographically unsound and [has been broken](https://events.ccc.de/congress/2007/Fahrplan/events/2378.en.html) ([video](https://media.ccc.de/v/24c3-2378-en-mifare_security)), so that tags could be forged. However, that is way more involved than just hooking up some device or flashing something on an arduino.

So, at your apparent level of involvement with this: no. Instead of duplicating an ID card, you'll have to add another authorized ID card to whatever system you're dealing with.

Also: from your description it's not clear whether this is Mifare classic or one of the more recent versions, which are safe and can not be cloned at all, to the knowledge of the public.

If your system is using Mifare classic, urge the operator to upgrade, unless the risk / cost tradeoff doesn't support that.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't be surprised if there were applications that only read the card ID, or only store data on the card.

Comment: reading the ID would normally still be done after authenticating the card.